# Run jquery code on server side?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay here i am again with another question(s).

First off: Is there any solution in replacement for Node.js that we can use/install on shared hosting?

Second: is it possible to run a simple jQuery code on a server side? lets say we are using this code:

```
<script>
$( '#myButton' ).click(function() {
$( "#myDiv" ).effect( "puff", "slow" );
$( "#myDiv" ).toggle( "puff" );
});
</script>
```

how can i run this code 'server side' so once User1 clicks on the `#myButton`, the User2 whose viewing the same page will also see the puff effect applied to the `#myDiv` in real time?

I know this can be done via AJAX in a way but all the AJAX solutions that I tried/found was for one user (User1) and the other Users wont be able to see it in real time.

any help would be great.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to run jQuery code like that on the server. Things just don't work that way. You have to use some sort of networked solution, either HTTP (ajax) or web sockets, and the server code will look nothing like client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

User 1 and User 2 are two different browsers and sessions. So session, cookie etc will not help you out. I don't know why you are trying something like that but if you insist you can use database and set a flag true after user1 and show other users if flag is true...
I don't see any way else doing what you are trying to do easily.

Comment: But I am not trying to save anything into database! So how can I use flag true etc etc to run my jquery code?

Comment: You can not do that without saving it to somewhere. If your case was to show same user you could then use session, cookie etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you heard it right, you need  to use 2 ajax call per client.

```
1.When user clicks some thing update the id  or some value in database using ajax.

2.Call one ajax call repeatedly in some time interval and get the saved value in database to clientside, check the value and show the animation accordingly.
```

Comment: so this means we need 4 ajax calls for 2 users and 8 ajax calls for 4 users and so on and so forth ? and if so, isn't that going to put the server under pressure?

Comment: yes, in advanced technology  you can use Push notification of HTML5,  here you donot need to refresh at regular interval, server will notify you when there is a change

Comment: Then your solution is wrong! or a very bad approach I should say!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `run` your code on `realtime` then you should use [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

> **Socket.IO** aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and mobile device, blurring the differences between the different
>   transport mechanisms. It's care-free realtime 100% in JavaScript.

Comment: can socket.io be used on shared servers/hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Real-Time communication requires bidirectional communication between the server and the clients. Since web clients can only send requests but not receive such this is not so simple. There are a number of techniques that achieve this effect (Google them for more information):

- Polling (the simplest one)
- Long polling
- Web sockets
- BOSH

You can alternatively use some other bidirectional communication protocol (not HTTP) like XMPP.

The simplest solution in my opinion would be to use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). Their services are not free if you expect more than 20 connections but make bidirectional communication in every kind of project a piece of cake.